# Base64 code to prevent attack on the website

Tags: security, web, base64

If I am using base64 to prevent enumeration attacks, is base64 good enough.

36667 order id = corresponds to the base code TCxJ1cxT5Is=

Is it possible to reverse engineer the base64 here back to the 36667?

Thanks

Comment: *reverse engineer*? Base64 can be decoded by anyone and anyone can also create another number and encode it again. Base64 is simple encoding, not encryption.

Comment: I mean, whether you can work our the relationship between the code I have above to reverse engineer it to somehow reach 36667?